# jpackage missing "mac.Appstore" bundle type

Tags: java, macos, jpackage

The old retired `javapackager` tool used to have 3 bundle types for mac os x:

- dmg
- pkg
- mac.Appstore

But the new `jpackage` tool only has 2 types:

- dmg
- pkg

The `mac.Appstore` type was previously used when packaging the app to be submitted to Mac Appstore.
It would automatically find two certificates (installer and application) and use it to sign both the app and pkg files.

This option doesn't seem to exist in the new jpackage tool.

My question: is there an option to build packages for Mac Appstore with `jpackage` that I somehow missed? Or is this option gone forever? If so then what's the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted request to include this feature in jpackage:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8248904

**Update:** This feature is added to JDK 17

Comment: Hey Saeid, I was wondering if you managed to publish a JVM app using jpackage to the Mac App Store. I am running into issues with provisioning profiles for TestFlight. Got some clarification from Apple about this and it appears that `jspawnhelper` needs a provisioning profile, too; Did you try to get an app on TestFlight by any chance?

Comment: Yes I did publish my app in mac app store. It's called "Graphing Calculator 3D". But I didn't use TestFlight. I don't recall provisioning problems. Can you copy and paste the details of the error you get?